# C rewriting an array using function, avoiding pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function

i have searched thoroughly and could not find an answer to my question.

i would like a function in my code to rewrite an already existing array. i would like it to be local array-meaning an array that is defined and initialized inside main.
i would like to execute without using pointers.

i think it should be possible because of the fact that arrays are actually pointers(as far a read).

this is my code, for what its worth:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void minusone_array_rewrite(int food_arr[5][2]);
int main()
{
    int food_arr[5][2] = {0};
    minusone_array_rewrite(food_arr[5][2]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)////just printing
    {
        printf("%d", food_arr[i][0]);
        printf("%d", food_arr[i][1]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void minusone_array_rewrite(int food_arr[5][2]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        food_arr[i][0] = -1;
        food_arr[i][1] = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What precisely is the problem? I don't get your question, you wanna do a thing, then you did it, so what are you asking about? Clarify please.

Comment: You calling the function with an `int` as the argument but the function expects an array.  Also, as @StoryTeller asked, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you said by yourself arrays in C are pointers themselves, the problem I see is initialization of your array and passing it to function `minusone_array_initializer`.

The correct way would be :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void minusone_array_initializer(int food_arr[5][2]);
int main()
{
    int food_arr[5][2];

    minusone_array_initializer(food_arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d , %d \n",food_arr[i][0],food_arr[i][1]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void minusone_array_initializer(int food_arr[5][2]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        food_arr[i][0] = -1;
        food_arr[i][1] = -1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: why is it working? How come other function know about `food_arr` location ?

Comment: @SayedSohan because I pass array (actually pointer to the first element) to the function

Comment: *"arrays in C are pointers themselves"* - Not quite. They decay to ones everywhere, but their non-pointer nature rears its heads more often than not.